# JQuery: button inside Modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, button, modal-dialog

I am trying to select a row in a Table inside a Modal window and then have a button('newBtn') inside that Modal window send a post request to the server with the selected id of the row.
That button should send the data of the last selected row when pressed, however it sends as many posts as there have been previous clicks on a row (and not only the last one).So if row 1,2,3 have been clicked previously, it will send 3 posts and not just 1 post with row 3 selection.
I suspect the brackets are not placed correctly however when taking the button outside the modal function, it will not fire at all. Any help kindly appreciated.

```js
var table= $('#example').DataTable();
    var tableBody = '#example tbody';
    var form = new FormData();

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(tableBody).on('click', 'tr', function () {

            var cursor = table.row($(this));//get the clicked row
            var selected_id = cursor.data()[0];// this will give the id in the current row.

            $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
                $("#testbutton").trigger("click");
            });


            $("#newBtn").on("click",function(){
                form.set("selected_id", selected_id);

                var settings = {
                    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/test",
                    "method": "POST",
                    "timeout": 0,
                    "processData": false,
                    "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
                    "contentType": false,
                    "data": form
                };

                $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });

            });

        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="min-width: 1080px">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">

          <table class="display" id="example" style="text-align: center; width: 100%">

            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Date</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>'2020-06-01'</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>'2020-06-02'</td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

        <button type="button" id="newBtn" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Send post</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var table= $('#example').DataTable();
var tableBody = '#example tbody';
var form = new FormData();
```

Use this code inside

```
$(document).ready(function() { });
```

And remove the below script

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the script in the header is actually

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

So you are suggesting :

```html
var table= $('#example').DataTable();
    var tableBody = '#example tbody';
    var form = new FormData();

    $(document).ready(function() { });

    $(tableBody).on('click', 'tr', function () {

        var cursor = table.row($(this));//get the clicked row
        var selected_id = cursor.data()[0];// this will give the id in the current row.

        $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
            $("#testbutton").trigger("click");
        });


        $("#newBtn").on("click",function(){
            form.set("action", "select_id");
            form.set("selected_id", selected_id);

            var settings = {
                "url": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/test",
                "method": "POST",
                "timeout": 0,
                "processData": false,
                "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
                "contentType": false,
                "data": form
            };

            $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });

        });

    });
```

This still doesn't solve it on my end: when you select row 1 and then row 2 the button will send 2 posts instead of only 1 desired post with row 2 as data